# How to get count of unique rows in a file?

Tags: text-processing

I have a list of identifiers in column 1 and corresponding counts in column 2. The file looks something like this:

```
KDO65387         65
KDO65387         27
XP_006465447     971
XP_006482015     1207
XP_003630414     194
XP_002513282     500
XP_003630414     23
```

What I want is to sum the values in column#2 if the values in the column#1 in consecutive rows match. The output will look like this:

```
KDO65387    92
XP_006465447    971
XP_006482015    1207
XP_003630414    217
XP_002513282    500
```

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: Only consecutive? i.e. is `a 1/b 2/a 3` the same or `a 4/b 2`?

Answer (score 3):

If the order matters:

```
awk '!($1 in sum) {f[n++] = $1}
     {sum[$1] += $2}
     END {for (i = 0; i < n; i++) print f[i], sum[f[i]]}' < file
```

If it doesn't, you can simplify it to:

```
awk '{sum[$1] += $2}
     END {for (f in sum) print f, sum[f]}' < file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `datamash`:

```
datamash groupby 1 sum 2 <infile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lane '
   exists $h{$F[0]} or push @h, $F[0];
   $h{$F[0]} += $F[1];
   END { print "$_\t$h{$_}" for @h; }
' yourfile
```

The above will print the keys in the order they were encountered. The array maintains the order of the keys whilst the hash maintains the sum corresponding to each key.